# InfoMessages are truncated if added after the query

Tags: vb.net, t-sql

When using ExecuteReader in combination with InfoMessages event the last InfoMessages are not raised - if the query produces no rows. If the query produces rows you can see the InfoMessages in the end. Sample query that returns no rows might look like this:

```
PRINT 'this is the start of the test'
print CHAR(10) + CHAR(13);

Select top(0) 1,  2, 3;
    
print CHAR(10) + CHAR(13);
print 'this is the end of the test'
```

In the example above the InfoMessages even are not raised for the last two rows. It is only raised if the middle query returns something.

Sample code, simplified:

```
' add handler
AddHandler Cmd.Connection.InfoMessage, AddressOf InfoMessageReceived

' execute query
reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader
While reader.Read()
strValue = reader.GetValue(i).ToString()
End While

' remove handler
RemoveHandler Cmd.Connection.InfoMessage, AddressOf InfoMessageReceived

' consolidate output
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Does it raise an exception?  The online docs suggest that an error will halt the `ExecuteReader` and throw.  In that case, it wouldn't get to the second `print` sequence.  Note that VB-side, this might be ignored as with `On Error Resume Next` (held over from VBA-heritage VB for compatibility), I'm not sure if there is a server-side equivalent.

Comment: This post needs more code. Something is missing. At minimum a try/catch and using blocks for the data connection. Please update with more code of you still need an answer. I'd you already answered your own question, please add an answer below and make it as such.

Comment: There are no exceptions. InfoMessage is not just raising any more events after ExecuteReader has no more output. I will think about how I can add more code without making it complicated.